# How to phrase topic sentence

Tags: topicizing

I am writing an essay on why time travel is actually possible; i.e. actually has a chance of happening in the future. I don't know what my topic sentence should be.

"Time travel is possible" doesn't sound strong

Would something like "Time travel has a significant probability of occuring in the future" be okay? I need it to sound strong.

Comment: write the whole essay first and then write the topic sentence. the topic sentence will give the reader a little taste of the persuasive force that they will be treated to in the remainder of the essay.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks for advice on literary/rhetorical structure.

Comment: Should be on writer's exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, strong writers will contend that shorter, simpler sentences tend to be better.

I would recommend not adding any words to the sentence that make it longer without changing its meaning.

So, perhaps something like

> Contrary to popular belief, time travel is possible.

It may also benefit you to use an active formulation rather than a passive. e.g.:

> Contrary to popular belief, humankind may achieve time travel.

Finally, if you are writing a paper in which you are meant to make an argument, your topic sentence (often called a thesis statement) should summarize your argument, and may be phrased using personal constructions:

> In this paper, I will argue that, contrary to popular belief, humankind may achieve time travel.

These are all just ideas, but hopefully they offer something helpful.

Answer (score 2):

> Time travel has always been a fascination for the human race. From fictional stories by great authors such as H. G. Wells, to ancient Greek and Egyptian mythologies, time travel has always been a subject of intense debate and speculation. With the scientific advancements of the past twenty years alone, time travel might be a lot closer to becoming an actual reality.

Something like that?

Since this is an *essay*, I would write an introduction that like this.

In the end, it's a style preference. Certainly a short sentence will convey the message across quicker and more efficiently, but it may be lacking in other parts. Perhaps my version is too wordy.

Answer (score 0):

How about "The future reality of time travel?"